# Oracle Date - How to add years to date

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, date-arithmetic

I have a date field

```
DATE = 10/10/2010
```

sum = 4 (this are number of years by calculation)

is there a way to add four years to 10/10/2010 and make it
10/10/2014?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try adding months (12 * number of years) instead. Like this-

```
add_months(date'2010-10-10', 48)
```

Answer (score 28):

Use `add_months`

Example:

```
SELECT add_months( to_date('10-OCT-2010'), 48 ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Warning**
add_months, returns the last day of the resulting month if you input the last day of a month to begin with.

So `add_months(to_date('28-feb-2011'),12)` will return 29-feb-2012 as a result.

Answer (score 13):

I believe you could use the `ADD_MONTHS()` function. 4 years is 48 months, so:

```
add_months(DATE,48)
```

Here is some information on using the function:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/add_months.php

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1157035034361

Answer (score 10):

You can try this:

`someDate + interval '4' year`

[**INTERVAL**](http://psoug.org/definition/INTERVAL.htm)

Comment: Just a recommendation. Avoid using INTERVAL datatype. It is ANSI/ISO compliant. Therefore the statement you wrote will not work for 29th Feb. Generally it is up to you to grantee that the result will be correct. While add_months is Oracle proprietary and generates valid dates in for cases.

Comment: @ibre5041 Sorry to raise this post from the grave, but I was looking for a way to do this without having it stick to the last day of the month when calculating birthdays because add_month() fails for 2/28. When the next year is a leap year add_months(to_date('02-28','MM-DD')) returns 02-29, which isn't correct. I found doing the following always returns the correct date: (to_date('02-28','MM-DD') - 1) + interval '1' year + 1 returns 02-28, even if the next year is a leap year, and if you put in 02-29, it will return 03-01 on non-leap years.

Comment: @Bob Sadly, though, `select (to_date('01-31','mm-dd') -1 ) + interval '1' month +1 from dual;` always blows up with `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified`.

Comment: But we are adding years, not months.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure, if I understood Your question correctly, but

```
select add_months(someDate, numberOfYears * 12) from dual
```

might do the trick

Comment: Works for leap years, too.

Answer (score 4):

One more option apart from ADD_MONTHS

```
SELECT
      SYSDATE,
      SYSDATE
      + TO_YMINTERVAL ( '1-0' )
FROM
      DUAL;


SYSDATE   SYSDATE+TO_YMINTERVAL('1-0')
--------- ----------------------------
29-OCT-13 29-OCT-14                   
1 row selected.


SELECT
      SYSDATE,
      SYSDATE
      + TO_YMINTERVAL ( '2-0' )
FROM
      DUAL;


SYSDATE   SYSDATE+TO_YMINTERVAL('2-0')
--------- ----------------------------
29-OCT-13 29-OCT-15                   
1 row selected.

SELECT
      TO_DATE ( '29-FEB-2004',
              'DD-MON-YYYY' )
      + TO_YMINTERVAL ( '1-0' )
FROM
      DUAL

   *
Error at line 4

ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

But the last one is illegal since there is no 29th day of February in 2005, hence it fails on leap year cases (Feb 29)

Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#sthref327) for the same

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-2 ANO FROM DUAL
```