# Subtracting 30 Years from Current Date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query in which I select all people who have a date of birth over 30 years ago. Unfortunately, as I am using Oracle I cannot use the `DATEADD()` function.

I have currently got this, but obviously this isn't dynamic and won't change as the years pass:

```
SELECT Name, DOB
FROM Employee
WHERE DOB <= DATE '1985-01-01';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313234/oracle-date-how-to-add-years-to-date

Comment: 1) SYSDATE can be useful 2) What is your DOB type ?

Comment: "Unfortunately, as I am using Oracle I cannot use the DATEADD() function." That's not unfortunate as you're fortunate enough to be using Oracle which has many other powerful functions to use when dealing with dates.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Add_MONTHS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm) to *add* `(- 12 * 30)`.

```
SELECT Name, DOB
FROM Employee
WHERE DOB <= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -(12 * 30));
```

Comment: @Habib I think you forgot the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

Other way, using intervals:

```
SELECT Name, DOB
FROM Employee
WHERE DOB <= sysdate - interval '30' year;
```

Comment: Be aware, however, that this throws an error if the `sysdate` is on Feb 29 of a leap year.  Subtracting the interval returns Feb 29 of a year 30 years prior which, by definition, is not a leap year so the date is invalid.  You'd get an ORA-0139 error.

Answer (score 0):

simply use `ROUND((sysdate - DOB)/365)`:

```
SELECT Name, DOB
FROM Employee
WHERE ROUND((sysdate - DOB)/365) <= 30;
```

Comment: If you're going to do that, you'd want to use `months_between`, not subtraction and division.  Leap years have 366 days so you'll be 7 or 8 days off in your calculation.

Comment: Sorry, plz notice the query uses `ROUN`