# SQL SUBQUERY in Sqlplus Oracle 11g Help please

Tags: sql, oracle11g, subquery, sqlplus

Im trying to write a query that will list the Consultant_Id, Name and age for all consultants who have a Grade of 'D' in my Consultant table, and were born more than 30 years ago and have a name that begins with the letter 'L'. I need the output ascending age order. so far i have this but i presume there is multiple errors, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not really sure where to start with that... there are multiple errors, but if you know that, can't to you try to address them? You're basically just asking us to write the query for you, which won't teach you much. (Irrelevant, but are you doing the same course as the OP of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28748104/266304)?)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, its not through trying, been stuck on this for hours and cant seem to get it working. Im ok with standalone queries but subqueries i cant get my head around.

Comment: Why are you doing subqueries at all though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to seem to be attacking you, but since you said you've been trying to figure this out for a long time and you're stuck, let's look at some of the problems with what you have at the moment.

```
SELECT Consultant_Id, Name, DOB,
```

This line has a trailing comma.

```
FROM Consultant;
```

This line has a semicolon at the end, terminating the statement, so your where clause is a separate invalid command.

```
WHERE DOB = (SELECT MAX(DOB <= 01-jan-85) FROM CONSULTANT)
```

You seem to be using `01-jan-85` as a date, but even if it was in single quotes it would be a string not a date and you should explicitly convert it to a date type; without quotes it would get an invalid identifier (trying to treat 'jan' as a column name). Using the `<=` comparator inside a `max()` call isn't valid anyway, and I'm not quite sure what it's supposed to achieve. At best you're getting the most recent DOB from the table in the subquery, and then using that to filter the main query so you will only get the row (or maybe rows) that match that exact date. It won't give you all DOBs more than 30 years ago.

```
WHERE name( SELECT SUBSTR(Name,1,20) LIKE 'L%' AS ShortName)
```

`name()` isn't a function, so perhaps you meant to compare it with `=`; but as with the DOB check that isn't really what you wan. Your subquery doesn't have a `from` clause, and isn't correlated with the main query so would return multiple rows, which is an error in itself. As this is the second filter you should be using `AND` rather than a second `WHERE`. And the `substr()` isn't really adding anything since you're using `like` anyway.

```
WHERE Grade = 'D'
```

This is almost OK, but should also be `AND` not `WHERE.

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(DOB, 7,9);
```

This is doing an implicit conversion of DOB to a string, then getting characters 7 to 15 of whatever your session converts it to by default. Based on the date string you used earlier you means `substr(dob, 7, 2)`, which would give you the 2-digit year in that format; but you're supposed to be ordering by the whole DOB, not just the year.

@HepC has given the actual command you need (aside from the trailing comma on the first line).

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your constructive criticism. I am currently taking notes of what you have written for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT consultant_id, name, DOB
  FROM consultant
 WHERE DOB <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 12 * -30)
   AND name LIKE 'L%'
   AND grade = 'D'
 ORDER BY DOB;
```

Comment: Thanks again for your time on this one, error im getting for this is ERROR LINE 2 missing expression?

Comment: @tomashby - this still has the trailing comma on the first line. It'll work if you remove that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT consultant_id, name, DOB
  FROM consultant
 WHERE DOB <= ADD_MONTHS((SYSDATE), -360)
   AND grade = 'D'
   AND name LIKE 'L%'
 ORDER BY DOB;
```

Comment: Thankyou so much!!! this has had me stumped for hours, would i be able to trouble you for an explanation to the -360?? it works perfectly thanks

Comment: The function ADD_MONTHS accepts a date as the first argument.  The second argument is the number of months to add.  It accepts a positive or negative integer.  If you supply a negative value, in this case -360, it will subtract that from the date argument.  We use sysdate which provides the current date at the time the command is executed.  360 months = 30 years.  Please let me know if I can help further.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it really helped, the where line is the only one i could not figure out. Im just taking notes now on the useful comments i have been given, thanks again.

Comment: No problem.  Happy to help any time.

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT Consultant_Id, Name AS ShortName, DOB
    FROM Consultant
    WHERE DOB < dateadd(year, -30, getdate())
    AND name LIKE 'L%' 
    AND Grade = 'D'
    ORDER BY DOB
```

Comment: Dateadd and getdate aren't valid for Oracle.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help with this, just one error has come back, it is; error at line 3: "dateadd" : invalid identifier

Comment: You`re welcomed Tom. Sorry I missed the Oracle spec.