# How to determine future date

Tags: sql, oracle

Knowing a user's date of birth, how can I determine the date they will reach a certain age?

I can calculate current age, but need to determine when, based on that calculation, to get the date of when they will turn a certain age, such as what date they will turn 18.

```
FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(sysdate), v.date_of_birth) / 12) age
```

Comment: By writing some SQL.  You should try it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has shown no effort to solve the problem on his own.

Comment: I have been trying SQL for quite awhile. I can calculate current age, but need to determine when, based on that calculation, to get the date of when they will turn a certain age, such as what date they will turn 18. FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(sysdate), v.date_of_birth)
                    / 12) age

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Date - How to add years to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313234/oracle-date-how-to-add-years-to-date)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`add_months`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm) function:

```
select add_months(birthdate, 12 * age) from t
```

Comment: I guess we don't encourage people to learn and research anything on their own?  It's all about the points...

Comment: Guess you're assuming I didn't research this on my own. Didn't realize this community had that attitude.

Comment: @KatherynOverman Common sense would dictate you post the SQL code you have tried and explain the problem you are having.  None of which you did in your post.  I guess you expect us to be mind readers?

Comment: A simple request to post my code would have sufficed. I didn't realize that was a requirement.  Arrogance and sarcasm were not necessary.You must be a real joy to work with/for.

Comment: @Katheryn Please don't mind him. For a future question, please think as if you have to answer it - "does the question make sense? Does the question show any research effort?" While you're working on this, you probably will figure out the answer yourself. If not, post it. We'll see.