# Is it possible to add INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH data type to a date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a YEAR(2) TO MONTH data type column, is it possible to add that to a DATE datatype column, or even SYSDATE?

Comment: You may need to elaborate more with sample data and examples of input and output.

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313234/oracle-date-how-to-add-years-to-date/9313346

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Date - How to add years to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313234/oracle-date-how-to-add-years-to-date)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add intervals to dates.  The result is another date.

E.g.,

```
create table interval_test (year_month_interval INTERVAL YEAR(2) TO MONTH);

insert into interval_test values ( interval '1-5' year(2) to month );  -- 1 year and 5 months

select to_char(sysdate+year_month_interval,'DD-MON-YYYY') from interval_test;
```

This will return a date that is 1 year and 5 months in the future.